# Do insurance companies pay for ancestral DNA testing?

Tags: dna

Do insurance companies pay for ancestral DNA testing? I tried to look it up but could find nothing, so I went on a online and a man said not to trust the census records.

Comment: Many companies who offer client services are expanding their offerings. Not a direct answer, but It might be of interest to read https://blog.eogn.com/2016/06/13/financial-firms-offer-a-new-service-to-wealthy-clients-family-history/

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean medical insurance?

Alas, insurance companies do not exist to fund our hobby. DNA testing for ancestry research uses different markers and methodology than most medical DNA tests. Medical DNA tests typically look for specific genetic markers of diseases, while ancestry tests look at markers in the genome which vary between individuals and allow us to assess genetic relationships.

Whether your insurance company will cover a medical DNA test recommended by your doctor is something that you must discuss with your insurance company directly.

However, each year ancestral DNA tests are becoming more affordable, and there are often discounts available if you do a bit of hunting. For example, FamilyTreeDNA's FamilyFinder autosomal test is [currently $99](https://www.familytreedna.com/family-finder-compare.aspx).